# Login dialog when looking at pages in subfolders

Tags: iis-7, asp.net

I have copied over my site from another server ( Folders containing the site ) and when i use them on my new server (2008) i get a login dialog when i try to access pages that have their aspx page located in a subfolder. If i use the login dialog and login with a valid account on that server, IIS will give me a 404 error ( File is physically there on my server).

My first thought was this was NTFS rights issue, but it does not seem to be the case. I have set owner to administrators group, and i have also tried giving the everyone group full control with the same result.

All the aspx pages in the root folder function as needed.

Comment: Just a suggestion: it is not the best idea to just change permissions to administrators group, as you are creating a possibly vulnerable situation.
Further, the administrators group doesn't always necessarily have "all' permissions, you should focus more on the IIS-related users/permissions (as suggested below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got away, but i dont understand why. Or after i published the website via VS ( Debug mode if that mathers ) to the IIS folder. After that everything worked perfectly. 
Il leave the Question open for a while longer, if someone can actualy explain what happen il accept that as their reply

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you've covered all of the permissions?  It sounds as though the IIS account (usually IUSR_xxxxxxx) doesn't have read permissions to those sub-folders.

Comment: IIS_IUSRS Seems to be the account on my machine, but i tried using everyone just for testing but that also failed. I still get the  login dialog ( Also updated question with new info)

Answer (score 2):

Try and do it again using the IIS migration tool, if you can. you'll find it for free at downloads.microsoft.com. We successfully use this to migrate HUGE amounts of data AND iis settings for fairly big and complex websites. You could also robocopy the files and use the IIS Migration Tool for migration IIS Settings.

If you want to do it manually, you'll just have to compare NTFS and IIS settings between the old and the new site.

Also check any possible ISAPI filters and/or .Net versions to make sure everything is the same on old and new box.

Comment: I tried copying the site with the migration tool, but i got the same results. Updated question with new info